# Electric Range: no 220v funtionality

Tags: range

Frigidaire FED355 Electric range. Oven and stove-top in use, heard loud 'Phump', and it all goes dead, clock, lights, etc. Warm plastic aroma. Reset breaker. Range top lights, clock, timer now work.

No fault or error codes.

Can set oven temperature or broiler high/ low, relay clicks, but no heat on either element.

Voltage at elements shows 120v to ground from each leg, but 0 between the two legs.

Also, any sources for diagram to remove board? I've pulled most every panel, sides, top, rear, but can't remove front control panel. Thanks.

Comment: Do the range elements heat?

Comment: You could start by unplugging the range and checking the voltage at the plug. If you get 0v between the legs at the plug, it indicates that your circuit breaker has fused its nodes, or "Phumped", and must be replaced.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri -- he has voltage at the elements, so I doubt the breaker is the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you've lost one phase (the one *not* running the clock, lights, etc). You'll measure 120V on both sides of the elements because you're measuring the good phase through the element.

Comment: @brhans: Good call. I forgot about voltage detectable through the element. -- That's a better reason to unplug and check the voltage at the outlet.

Comment: Maybe one side of the breaker did not reset. Turn the breaker all the way off and then reset it.

Comment: What about the sound and smell? This is a very common problem there are several videos out there for different models and the root cause is all the same the Relay fried sometimes totally destroying the board for the oven section sometimes the entire board. On occasion the relay can be replaced but the more arc's the board takes the less likely that will be.

Answer (score 1):

A common problem with ranges is the control board relays fry taking out some of the range functionality. I fixed one that just the oven did not work another that everything was dead. I would [start here](http://www.partselect.com/Models/FED355ASE/Sections/WIRING-DIAGRAM/?ModelID=905072&ModelNum=FED355ASE&mfgModelNum=&ManufactureID=&Selected=D70RXDFB&Position=6&mfg=Frigidaire&Type=Washer&Mark=6) with the range unplugged look at the the control board there are usually several larger plastic covered relays look for damage on the board. since you mentioned the plastic smell it would be a good starting point. I found the parts for 1 range for 50-60$ the self cleaning convention oven was over 200, that was cheap compared to 1300 for a new one. here is a link to a [utube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYOfQ5lbRQ0) on how to do it. Added, The relays switch both legs of the 240V if 1 leg of the relay fried (the noise and burn smell) you would read 120 to ground from both ends of the element.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, we use 240V and put our neutral midway between.  This gives us two "legs", call them L1 and L2, and neutral in the middle between.   L1 to neutral is 120V.  Neutral to L2 is 120V.

Ovens use 240V for heat (L1 to L2).  But they use 120V for the oven light bulb and controls, so they grab that between one leg (say L1) and neutral.

So imagine you have a broken wire in L2.  L1 and netutral are good - controls and oven light work.  But L2 is bad, so no heat.

That sounds like your symptom.